# I have problem with bootstrap buttons when resizing browser

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have this in my html:

```css
.btn {
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 10em;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container-fluid  mb-5">
  <div class="row ">
    <div class="col pl-0 pr-0 ml-5">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">ONE</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col pl-0 pr-0 ml-5">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">TWO</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col pl-0 pr-0 ml-5 mr-5">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">THREE</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem that I am having is that when I resize browser buttons stick to the right side and to eachother. What can be done here? Any help appreciated!

Comment: may I ask what do you want it to look ?

Comment: when resizing no change with spacing

Comment: code works until I resize and button three jumps in second row

Comment: yes, and also margin right the same as when not resized

Comment: It's bootstrap: ml-5 mr-5

Comment: guys check my answer. I think this is what he expect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Please run this in your browser rather than using snippet to have a better response

See I have changed one thing in your code . What I did was just added **`col-sm`** for div classes. You can find more about bootstrap grid system via this link. [Bootstrap grid system](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/) .

I think you expect this.

[image: snap]

To see the result please expan the snippet and then with Inspect Element in you browser and then navigate to mobile view . Thanks

### Update

In addition to what you asked at the chat I have added some custom css which is responsive to increase the font size . Just added `style="font-size:5vw;"`.The text size can be set with a `vw` unit, which means the "viewport width".

That way the text size will follow the size of the browser window:

This is the new view after adding `style="font-size:5vw;"`

[image: new view]

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container-fluid  mb-5 ">
       <div >
    <div class="container-fluid  mb-5 ">
      <div class="row ">
      <div class="col pl-0 pr-0 ml-5 col-sm-3">
          <button type="button"  style="font-size:5vw;" class=" btn btn-primary btn-block">ONE</button>
      </div>
      <div class="col pl-0 pr-0 ml-5 col-sm-3">
          <button type="button"  style="font-size:5vw;" class=" btn btn-primary btn-block">TWO</button>
      </div>
      <div class="col pl-0 pr-0 ml-5 mr-5 col-sm-3">
          <button type="button"  style="font-size:5vw;" class=" btn btn-primary btn-block">THREE</button>
      </div>
</div>
```